# Displaying Data according to the date added in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, date, html-table, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and Firestore for the backend. I have a table with a single column "Details". Now when data is added by a form, it is displayed in the table but in random order of date\time added. I would like to display as last data in the topmost row, basically descending date\time. I don't want to have date\time column. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: I am not an expert in Firebase, but I don't think even it can sort data on a non-existent field...